# How to get the template type from a typedef

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

My goal is to automatically replace *????* with INT16 without passing INT16 as a template parameter:

```
#include <windows.h>

typedef Address<INT16> Address2Bytes;
// Address is a class made by me with constructor Address<Data>(const char*, const Data&)

template <typename Addr>
void doStuff(const char* addressName, const ????& addressData)
{
    Addr address(addressName, addressData);// This variable MUST be created here

    // Do stuff
}

void main(void)
{
    doStuff<Address2Bytes>("name", 0x0);// Can't pass INT16 as a template (please don't ask why)
}
```

Explanation why I cannot replace with INT16:
The real doStuff function is something like this:

```
template <typename Addr>
void freeze(const String& processName, const String& addressName, const ????& data)
{
    Process process = processes[processName];
    Addr& address = process.getAddress<Addr>(addressName);

    address.data = data;
    address.frozen = true;
}
```

It is a library function and the library user does not need to know what an INT16 is, he only needs to know the address points to 2 bytes of memory.

Comment: Explain why you can't simply replace ???? with INT16, as in:  template <typename Addr>
void doStuff(const char* addressName, const INT16& addressData)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you could just deduce the type of `addressData` and have the function fail to compile in the constructor if the type is invalid:

```
template <typename Addr, typename DataType>
void doStuff(const char*, const DataType& );
```

If that is unsatisfactory for some reason, you could use a type trait to determine what the template type on `Address` is:

```
template <typename T> struct address_type;

template <typename T>
struct address_type<Address<T> > {
    typedef T type;
};
```

Which you can then use in your function:

```
template <typename Addr>
void doStuff(const char* addressName,
    const typename address_type<Addr>::type& addressData)
{ .. }
```

When you call `doStuff<Address2Bytes>` it will instantiate the `address_type<Address2Bytes>` template, whose `type` member will be `INT16`. If you tried to call `doStuff` with a type that wasn't an `Address`, this would fail to compile, which is probably OK.

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for, the compiler auto deduces it for me. Thanks for  taking the time to answer my question.